# How to create a looping iterator in python?

Tags: python, iterator

In python 3.8.6 I want to create an iterator which starts again from the beginning if all elements are used. So the list should repeat indefinitely.

Example code, raises `StopIteration`.

```
myiter = iter(["r", "g", "b", "m", "c", "k"])
for _ in range(100):
    print(next(myiter))
```

Of course I can implement it as follows:

```
mylist = ["r", "g", "b", "m", "c", "k"]
counter = 0
for _ in range(100):
    print(mylist[counter])
    counter += 1
    if counter==len(mylist):
        counter = 0
```

but it does not look very pythonic. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I think you're looking for `itertools.cycle`.

Comment: Do you want to _implement_ or _have_ such an iterator?

Comment: `for i in range(100): print(mylist[i % len(mylist)])`…